# How to automatically add a computer to a domain from a Powershell script using a non-administrator user

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, active-directory

I have a number of computers that will need to be added to our domain. The issue is the user that these computers log in with are not administrator users. We do have administrator users on the machines though.

I am trying to have a Powershell script run from a batch script, but nothing I do is giving me the correct results. It seems that even if the Powershell script runs as an administrator, because the batch script is not run as an administrator (it is run automatically on startup), I get a credential error. I've tried running a self-elevating PS script, but to no avail.

Here is one of the batch file lines I've tried:

```
    @echo off
    SET thisdir=%~dp0
    SET pspath=%thisdir%domain_add.ps1
    PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process Powershell -argumentlist '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%pspath%""' -verb runas}";
```

I've even tried using the batch file to start a powershell script, which then calls the add domain PS script:

```
    $user = '.\alohaadmin'
    $passfile = 'alohapass.txt'
    $password = Get-Content $passfile | ConvertTo-SecureString
    $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $password

    Start-Process 'powershell.exe' -Credential $cred -ArgumentList '-noexit','-file "domain_add.ps1"'
```

The issue seems to be with the initial batch file not being run as an admin.

Comment: In order to get help with your code, it'd be nice to show your code ;)

Comment: What are you currently trying?

Comment: How are you running the startup script? e.g. Scheduled task? (in that case there is a checkbox to run with highest privileges). Also, why run a batch script to run a PowerShell script? nowadays you can usually run the PowerShell script directly.

Comment: It is not running through a Powershell script. There is actually a batch script that runs that kicks off another program. I am trying to add the line to kick off this batch script at the end of that batch script.